# É uma boa prática armazenar um objeto JSON em uma data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, json

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg questao" data-json="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button><BR/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg questao" data-json="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button><BR/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg questao" data-json="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>



$(document.body).on("click",".questao",function(){
  var thisPosicao = $(".questao").index(this);
  var thisElement = $("#myModal").find(".modal-body").find("input");
  var array = [];
  thisElement.data("posicao",thisPosicao);
  //addTo.val(addTo.data("posicao");

  array.push({
    "posicao": thisElement.data("posicao"),
    "teste": "questao"+thisPosicao
  });

  $(".questao").eq(thisPosicao).data("json", JSON.stringify(array));
  var getJson = $(".questao").eq(thisPosicao).data("json");


  alert(JSON.stringify(getJson));
});
```

No futuro haverá um loop para percorrer todos esses botões para pegar o data-json e enviar via ajax. 
Lembrando que isso é apenas um simples exemplo, no meu projeto haverá milhões de opções para o usuário selecionar como configuração antes de enviar via ajax.

É Uma boa prática armazenar um JSON em uma `data-attribute`?
Tenho um projeto que vai ter que fazer um loop e pegar todas as informações armazenadas em cada `input` de diferentes tipos (pegar o valor checkado de um `checkbox`, o valor digitado em um `input text`, etc).

Nesse projeto também haverá um modal para selecionar mais opções de configurações, a minha ideia era armazenar esse dado dentro de um `data-atribute` para depois ser lida e armazenada em um outro arquivo json (este será enviado ao servidor com todos as configurações que o usuário fez).

um exemplo que fiz:
https://jsfiddle.net/cr9nucw3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ferramentas existem para ser usadas. Depende da lógica que tens, se é melhor separar os dados que queres em diversos `data-` ou ter somente um `data-json` com um JSON dentro. Ambos estão corretos, ambos são boa prática.

Answer (score 2):

De um modo geral, não tem problema. Já considerou usar AngularJS? Ele tem um recurso que faz o mapeamento de um elemento para uma modelo diretamente, e sincroniza automaticamente para você.